# In simple form: how can I define a different class for boolean inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following in a simple_form initializer:

```rb
  config.wrappers :default, tag: "div", class: "my-form-group", error_class: "has-error" do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label, class: "my-label"
    b.use :input, class: "my-input"
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: "span", class: "help-inline" }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: "p", class: "help-block" }
  end
```

This generates the HTML I am hoping for:

```html
<div class="my-form-group string optional software_instance_status">
  <label class="my-label string optional" for="software_instance_status">Status</label>
  <input class="my-input string optional" type="text" name="software_instance[status]" id="software_instance_status">
</div>
```

Except, that I do not want this styling to apply to boolean fields (e.g. checkboxes).

How do I restrict this styling to inputs that are not boolean fields and/or how do apply a separate set of rules (specifically the input class) for boolean fields?

Comment: The config file has something like: `# Define the default class of the input wrapper of the boolean input.
  config.boolean_label_class = 'checkbox'` have you tried to leverage that? It seems like you can create a `custom_checkbox` class and apply that by default that overrides the other default.

Comment: Additionally you can create other wrappers to override the default and then specify the wrapper in your inputs e.g. `f.input :my_boolean, wrapper: :my_boolean_wrapper`